# Lubuntu 14.4LTS file creation

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I just finished installing Lubuntu 14.04 LTS and I think it is a great OS. However, it won't let me create folders directly from the right click menu - new folder, but only from the top menu, or by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're right-clicking in the File manager's window. If that is correct and if your file manager is PCManFM,

**If you choose `Detailed List View`**

- ensure that no file or folder is highlighted (or selected)
- then position your mouse cursor in any column other than the one titled "Name" in the main pane (not in the side-pane "Places") and *then* right-click.

Or, you can right-click anywhere in an empty area below the list of folders and files if such area is available.

**If you choose `Icon Mode`,**

things are simpler. Just don't have your mouse pointer over an icon or its title when you right-click!

Comment: That's okay, things can be a bit confusing at first :)